# Is it possible to setup a reverse proxy and do mutual auth between client and backend server?

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy

[image]

Is this configuration possible? I understand basic PKI, but adding a reverse proxy in the middle seems to pose some problems with the SSL handshake authentication step. Is it possible to do mutual authentication where the "Client" trusts the "Reverse Proxy" and the "Server" trusts the "Client" because the Reverse Proxy is somehow configured to forward the clients packets along without decrypting/re-encrytping?

**EDIT:** if this is possible what might the NGINX configuration look like, if it were used to setup the forwarding?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton if this is possible how would configure NGINX to do the forwarding?

Comment: I believe you would have the RP authenticating the client (possible mapping this to a user ID) and then passing that along in some header to the Server. This is similar to what an API gateway would do; perhaps looking at how JWT / OpenID Connect is used in such a deployment would be helpful if you end goal is a microservice architecture.

Comment: I agree @CameronKerr, but the client in my toy example corresponds to a IoT device that is identified/authenticated by the backend server via the last 10 hexes of the x.509 certificate hash. So the certificate must be allowed to pass through (i.e. forwarded.)